Send only to contacts currently subscribed works when the contact has several keywords assigned with different Status values?
Scenario: A contact has 2 keywords assigned (KEYWORD1 & KEYWORD2) and they are opted-IN to KEYWORD1 but Opted-OUT of KEYWORD2.
If I used as a sending option for SMS "Send only to Contacts Currently Subscribed" would in this case the contact receive the SMS or not?
thank you.

Yes, the SMS will send to this contact. The process of sending an SMS is a little counter-intuitive in how it's presented during send setup. You have the option of opting a contact into a keyword as part of the send process, but when you have multiple keywords being used for subscription, this is totally disconnected from what actually happens when you finalise the send and isn't directly related to the send itself.
In essence, if a contact is included in the send audience and they are opted into any keyword at all, they will receive the SMS.
So if you want to only send to contacts opted in to a particular keyword, you need to control this during the creation of your audience (and omit opted out records at this point) rather than at send time.

Hi @JarettBush thank you for your answer. In case I want to send an SMS to unsubscribed contacts (as a Transactional SMS) then the best solution would be to use a separate long/short code for this type of SMS correct?

It's not quite that simple. There is the concept of global unsubscribe keywords in MobileConnect eg STOP. If someone replies to your SMS using that keyword, they are opted out of all keywords. So that would hold true of your transactional sends too. Wihch means another long code doesn't solve your problem.
The way I generally deal with this scenario is with a few workarounds:

A keyword for commercial sends
A keyword for transactional sends
A keyword for opting out of commercial sends
An automation to resubscribe mobile numbers that opt out of the transactional keyword


And then every commercial send audience needs to check that the mobile number hasn't opted out of the commercial keyword
